# Identifying attacks by network activity

Tags: network, denial-of-service, ddos

Is it possible (and how) to tell from a network dump if there is a buffer overflow attack, DoS or brute force attack? A DDoS would be more obvious to identify, but those attacks mentioned above I think would look a little more like normal activity.

Sorry for my newbie question, your answer would help a lot. Any information on how to identify these attacks from network dumps would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on a number of factors, such as what protocol was used.

Let's assume for the sake of the answer that the protocol in question is unencrypted HTTP.

### Buffer Overflow.

This would be the trickiest of the 3 to identify, as it could just look like a large request.  It's possible that you could identify it from some common patterns that people use in Buffer Overflows (e.g. a series of 'A' characters) but that's not a requirement of the attack so in many cases it could be hard to detect, depending on how similar it looks to a standard request to the application

### DoS.

This should be relatively easy to spot from a Network dump.  You would likely see a large number of requests to the service either SYN packets (for a standard SYN flood attack) or perhaps a specific application request (like a search) for an application DoS, it would likely be visible as the volume of traffic to the service would go up quickly.

### Brute Force.

In most cases this would be quite easy to pick out from a network dump as you'd see a large number of unsuccessful logins to the application either coming from one IP address or a range (depending on whether the attack was distributed or not).  This would likely stand-out from ordinary traffic patterns, so be relatively easy to spot.